# What is the "Slain Monsters Rest in Peace" item property?

Tags: diablo-ii

I've had a look at some of the uniques available [here](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/elite/uarmor.shtml) and noticed that **Tyrael's Might** has a property called **"Slain Monsters Rest in Peace"**. What is this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Nature's Peace](http://classic.battle.net/diablo2exp/items/normal/urings.shtml) is a ring with that effect.

> Nature's Peace: "Slain Monsters Rest in Peace" means that the bodies can't be resurrected or they can't be used to raise skeletons (Necromancer). They can't be used for Corpse Explosion either. It will work only if you kill the enemy with a physical damage or elemental (Blizzard or Fireball) and not magical damage. The ring will work for the Paladin's Blessed Hammer skill.

Comment: Seems like an effect that is counter-effective (assuming you're playing a necromancer) considering I rely heavily on corpse-explosion.

Comment: Correct.  It is not a helpful effect when playing as a necromancer.  It is very helpful against a certain Act 5 boss.

Comment: or when playing with a Necromancer for that matter

Comment: @Marty It's primarily a tool against not just that Act 5 boss, but also against all manner of Shamans and the Greater Mummies. Which is what its *primary* effect is. I don't know if it stops the corpse-eating corpse-spewing fiends from Act 4, though.

Comment: I think it may also apply to the Assassin's Death Sentry, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does this also make them untargettable for the barbarian's corpse-looting skills (find potion/item?)

Comment: No. It basically nullifies the ability of the corpse to be used as a weapon (or to be resurrected). Druids' Vines, Barbarians' looting, Paladins' Redemption, all of those still work, but the corpse cannot be used for any skill that causes damage or brings the enemy back for more.

Answer (score -1):

Slain monsters Rest In Peace effectively stops skills like corpse explosion, find item/potion, redemption, etc from working on the would be corpse. This is specifically useful for hardcore players farming keys from Nihlathak, it basically makes him an easy target with not much killing power.